# Cannot connect to MQTT Broker from ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, mqtt, mq

I'm facing issues while connecting to my local MQTT Broker running in docker.

Here is my connection file:

```
import mqtt from 'mqtt';
const client = mqtt.connect({
  host: 'ws://192.168.31.46',
  port: 1883,
});
client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected');
  client.subscribe('SEND_MESSAGE', function (topic, message) {
    console.log({ topic, message });
  });
});
export default client;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port number is (99.9%) wrong, port 1883 is the native MQTT port not MQTT over WebSockets. What the correct port is will depend on how you have configured the broker (Assuming mosquitto, it does not have a WebSocket listener defined by default)

Also if the `mqtt.connect()` function is asking for a hostname and port then you shouldn't be give a URL to the post field. Remove the `ws://` from the start.

Comment: Thank you for nudging me in the right direction. I had the same issue, not understanding that we are using ws here.